# Ruby/rspec not recognizing Ruby class with the same name as a former module

Tags: ruby, class, rspec, module

I have a ruby class, Feedbin, that was previously the name of a module. When I try and call any methods in the class, a TypeError is thrown: `': Feedbin is not a class (TypeError)

When I change the name of the class, but appending an s for example, things seem to work as expected.

The same program used to have a module named Feedbin as well, but the module no longer exists.

Old:

```
module Feedbin
  class Api
  end
end
```

New:

```
class Feedbin
end
```

How can I get rid of the "Feedbin is not a class" type error? What is causing this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa How can I get rid of the "Feedbin is not a class" type error? What is causing this?

Comment: Write that in the text.

Comment: @ColbyAley Did u find the reason behind this? Facing the same problem since morning.

Answer (score 14):

A non-class module cannot be changed into a class. Once you define a (non-class) module, it cannot be changed into a class. You perhaps have:

```
class Feedbin
...
```

somewhere prior to where you have

```
module Feedbin
...
```

Change that `class` into `module`, or use a different name instead of `Feedbin` for one of those.

Or, does the error message occur for certain methods? Certain methods can be defined on classes only. For example, if you call `Feedbin.new`, or something that calls `initialize` on `Feedbin`, and change `Feedbin` into a non-class module, then that would cause an error. In such case, use a different name for the non-class module.

Comment: That is exactly what I have done. What is the cause of this? Are there any ways around it? What if I delete and re-create the file?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any instance where it says `class Feedbin`? If you are including other files, it might be written there.

Comment: I do. I also can't change the class back into a module since I need create objects from it.

Comment: I used to have a module, but I now have a class with the same name. Ruby is not recognizing my class. If I change it's name, it does, but not with the same name. I need it to be a class so that I can initialize it as an object.

Comment: You cannot have 2 constants with the same name, this is why Ruby doesn't allow you to have module and class with the same name. You must choose and change it in all app.

Comment: Right. I no longer have a module with the same. I no longer have any modules, for that matter.

Comment: This answer doesnt explain why this happens, how to avoid it, or how to "fix" the situation properly. "Change the class name" is a hack and not an acceptable answer - how does one stop Ruby from recognizing the module name, and to use the class name? - Its highly likely that there are still references to "module Feedbin" somehwere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem when running via web server.

The solution was to restart the server.